# Model-specific registers in go?

Tags: go, assembly, x86, plan-9

I'm learning how to write assembly with Go, and I'm not very familiar with assembly. I'm trying to understand how to read from a model-specific register, and I'm running into errors.

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func readmsr(register int64) int64

func main() {
    fmt.Println(readmsr(0xC0000080))
}
```

```
// intrinsics_amd64.s
// readmsr(register int64) int64
TEXT ·readmsr(SB), $0-24
    RDMSR register+0(FP), AX
    MOVQ AX, ret+16(FP)
    RET
```

When I try to compile the code, I get these errors:

```
go build -v .
_/gopath/go/workspace/temp
# _/gopath/go/workspace/temp
asm: invalid instruction: 00000 (/gopath/go/workspace/temp/instrinsics_amd64.s:3)   RDMSR   register+8(FP), AX
asm: assembly failed
```

Looking the op codes in the [x86asm package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/arch/x86/x86asm#Op), it looks like `RDMSR` is a supported instruction, at least from what I can tell.

I am not very familiar with assembly, so I'm unsure if what I am doing wrong is wrong in assembly or wrong in Go. Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why it's wrong?

Comment: It is a supported instruction but it takes no operands, those are implicit. Try if simply `RDMSR` is accepted. That won't do what you want just yet though. You need to load the register number into `ecx` first.

Comment: Oh, okay, I followed your advice, and I definitely got it to compile. I didn't realise there were no operands on that instruction. Now it compiles and I'm getting memory errors, so I think now I just need to sort through why it's not working.

Comment: Also note `RDMSR` is a privileged instruction so if you are trying to run it in user mode it will fault.